# Print bytes of specific address

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I have the following code

```
intptr_t location = (intptr_t)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll.dll")), "NtReadFile");
printf("addr-> %p\n", location);
```

I am getting the following output:

```
0x00007FF9DE1FC120
```

I used x64dbg/IDA in order to see the opcodes in "0x00007FF9DE1FC120"

```
00007FF9DE1FC120 | 4C:8BD1                  | mov r10,rcx                             |
00007FF9DE1FC123 | B8 06000000              | mov eax,6                               |
00007FF9DE1FC128 | F60425 0803FE7F 01       | test byte ptr ds:[7FFE0308],1           |
00007FF9DE1FC130 | 75 03                    | jne ntdll.7FF9DE1FC135                  |
00007FF9DE1FC132 | 0F05                     | syscall                                 |
00007FF9DE1FC134 | C3                       | ret                                     |
00007FF9DE1FC135 | CD 2E                    | int 2E                                  |
00007FF9DE1FC137 | C3                       | ret                                     |
```

I am getting trouble printing 20 bytes which located at 0x00007FF9DE1FC120.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("|%x| ", (char)((location)+i));
    }
    printf("\n");
```

Output:

```
|20| |21| |22| |23| |24| |25| |26| |27| |28| |29|
```

I am expecting to get something like that

```
|4C| |8B| |D1| |B8| |06| |00| |00| |00| |F6| |04|
```

I will be happy to get your assistance,
Thanks

Comment: For start, you might want to dereference the location: `printf("|%x| ", (unsigned char)location[i]);`

Comment: And limit your conversion specifier to 1-byte, e.g. `"|%hhx| "`

Comment: @Quimby: `location` is `intptr_t location`, not a pointer.  The OP is printing the address, not the pointed-to data. `((unsigned char*)location)[i]` would work (and be strict-aliasing safe).  Passing to printf implicitly converts to `int` via default integer promotions.

Comment: @PeterCordes You are right, I missed that.

Comment: @ALevy PeterCordes is the one actually correct :)

Comment: @PeterCordes you are amazing thank you

Answer (score 5):

`location` is an integer type `intptr_t location`.  You're truncating that integer to `char` and printing that integer value, in this case printing the low byte of the pointer value.

You need to cast `location` back to a pointer.  To access a single byte (with zero-extension when the value is promoted to a wider `int` or `unsigned`), use `const unsigned char *`.  C / C++ strict-aliasing rules allow reading the object-representation of any object via an `unsigned char*`, as a special exception.  **This wouldn't be strictly safe with `const uint32_t*` for example.**

```
printf("|%x| ", ((const unsigned char*)location)[i] );
```

Or

```
const unsigned char *charloc = (const unsigned char*)location;
printf("|%x| ", charloc[i]);
```

Passing to printf implicitly converts to `int` via default integer promotions<sup>1</sup>.  You could use `%hhx` if you want, to tell printf to only print the low `unsigned char` of that int.

In C you can simplify the cast with `const unsigned char *charloc = (void*)location;`.  In C++11, you can avoid writing the type twice by using
`auto charloc = static_cast<const unsigned char*>(location);`.  In C, `auto` is just `int`, and in C++ `void*` doesn't freely convert to other pointer types.  So avoid these if you want to write code that's simultaneously valid C and C++.

---

Footnote 1:

`%x` is specified as taking `unsigned int` but there's no undefined behaviour because the standard allows `signed` and `unsigned` versions of the same integer type to be compatible for variadic / unprototyped arg-passing as long as the value is representable in both types. C17 § 6.5.2.2 6 for C, and presumably similar language in ISO C++ for variadic functions. (`unsigned char` ensures this, `signed char` could promote to negative `int` values.)

https://godbolt.org/z/Tevc48 shows that GCC and clang don't warn about it even with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`, even if you use `(int)charloc[i]` to make it explicitly `int`, not just a promotion result.

And it also shows the compiler using a `movzx esi, byte ptr[rbx]` load, loading a byte from memory with zero-extension like we want, as an arg for printf.  The compiler-generated asm from your version wouldn't be doing any loads, so you could have figured out that way that you weren't getting what you want.  (I assume you know assembly language better than C, given the tags?)

Comment: "Technically, %x wants an unsigned int not int, so this is still slightly sloppy." not sloppy per C17 § 6.5.2.2 6 "one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;",  `printf()` can't tell the difference.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - Thanks, didn't realize the standard made an exception for that mismatch with variadic / unprototyped args.

Answer (score 4):

An `intptr_t` is a signed integer that's large enough to hold a pointer.

Since you want to look at the data at that address, in this case you want an actual pointer:

```
unsigned char const *pos = (unsigned char const *)location;

for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    printf("|%2.2x| ", pos[i]);
```

The `%2.2x` assures that you'll get a leading 0 for a single-digit value, so (for example) zero will print out as `00` instead of just `0`.

Comment: `intptr_t` is large enough to hold an _object_ pointer, not necessarily a ProcAddress.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: For portable code, that would be true. In this case, we're dealing with Windows, and know it's large enough to hold the address of a function as well. For portable code, that would change (but would probably be a pretty minor part of the porting). Realistically, truly portable code can't do any of this though.